# Bricked GT P1010

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rom, samsung-galaxy-tab, unbricking, restore

I was trying yesterday to flash my p1010. I found on internet that I could put jellybean but it didn't work out and now my tab is stuck on the galaxy tab logo and is not booting the system. I'm able to go to download mode as well as to recovery mode and I tried to install new firmware on my tab but I can't find the right version anywhere on samfirmware.com there is only link to chinese vesrion and i bought mine in UK in 2011. 
IF anyone could send me over some links to good working firmware i'd be really thankfull ...

Comment: Please take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) to find a matching ROM (firmware).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the link](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-P1010)  containing the comprehensive list of firmare available for Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 Wi-Fi GT-P1010.

Download the correct file for your region and flash it.